# Obtaining sunlight exposition with GRASS GIS from EU DEM Maps

Tags: grass-gis, dem

I want to calculate the exposition to sunlight of any given point and taking the topography into account. I followed [this post](https://courses.neteler.org/eu-dem-new-digital-surface-model-at-25m/) and downloaded [a map](ftp://gisco-download:UC9T78H0g8@fts.ec.europa.eu/get/DG_ENTR-EUDEM/EU_DEM_1000K/EUD_CP-DEMS_4500015000-AA.zip) from the [EU DEM homepage](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/elevation/eu-dem-laea).

After downloading I registered the map via

```
r.external input=C:\Users\Sebastian\Downloads\EUD_CP-DEMS_4500015000-AA.tif output=elevationplot
```

Afterwards I plotted the layer to see if it works:

```
d.rast elevationplot@Seb
```

Now that I saw the raster image working and displaying the expected topography I wanted to obtain the desired raster with sunlight exposition data from:

```
r.sun --overwrite --verbose elevation=elevationplot@Sebastian insol_time=sunhours day=2
```

However this does not seem to work as r.info returns:

```
(Tue Apr 18 20:16:58 2017)                                                      
r.info map=sunhours@Sebastian                                                   
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Map:      sunhours@Sebastian             Date: Tue Apr 18 20:16:12 2017    |
 | Mapset:   Sebastian                      Login of Creator: Sebastian       |
 | Location: newLocation2                                                     |
 | DataBase: C:\Users\Sebastian\Documents\GIS DataBase                        |
 | Title:     ( sunhours )                                                    |
 | Timestamp: none                                                            |
 |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 |                                                                            |
 |   Type of Map:  raster               Number of Categories: 0               |
 |   Data Type:    FCELL                                                      |
 |   Rows:         1                                                          |
 |   Columns:      1                                                          |
 |   Total Cells:  1                                                          |
 |        Projection: unnamed                                                 |
 |            N:          1    S:          0   Res:     1                     |
 |            E:          1    W:          0   Res:     1                     |
 |   Range of data:    min = -1.#QNAN  max = -1.#QNAN                         |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Data Description:                                                        |
 |    generated by r.sun                                                      |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Comments:                                                                |
 |     ----------------------------------------------------------------       |
 |     Day [1-365]:                              2                            |
 |     Solar constant (W/m^2):                   1367                         |
 |     Extraterrestrial irradiance (W/m^2):      1412.707698                  |
 |     Declination (rad):                        -0.400084                    |
 |     Latitude min-max(deg):                    90.0000 - -90.0000           |
 |     Sunrise time min-max (hr.):               24.00 - 0.00                 |
 |     Sunset time min-max (hr.):                24.00 - 0.00                 |
 |     Time step (hr.):                          0.5000                       |
 |     Linke turbidity factor:                   3.0                          |
 |     Ground albedo:                            0.200                        |
 |     -----------------------------------------------------------------      |
 |                                                                            |
 |    r.sun --overwrite --verbose elevation="elevationplot@Sebastian" aspe\   |
 |    ct_value=270 slope_value=0.0 linke_value=3.0 albedo_value=0.2 insol_\   |
 |    time="sunhours" day=2 step=0.5 distance_step=1.0 npartitions=1          |
 |                                                                            |
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Since I am not experienced with using QGIS I don't know how to debug this code.

Comment: Region settings? (FAQ #0 in all GRASS processing)

Comment: @Micha: thank you for pointing me to the right direction. It took a bit research but I found the solution thanks to your hint!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the solution was fairly simple. As briefly pointed out in the comments I had to set a region for my computation:

```
g.region raster=elevationplot@Seb
```

The [computational region](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region) is explained in the Wiki.